# Multiple handler vs Single Handler in Netty

Tags: java, netty, nio

Are there any advantage of using Multiple handler over Single Handler in netty?

I have an application which handles millions of request per minute. 
Will writing code into single handler improve performance since less context switching or transfer of information will be needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you want to structure your netty program so that you encapsulate a reusable piece of logic into a handler. This way it is easy to compose processing logic and also test it. It is basically the same philosophy as you can find on *nix systems where you use `|` to combine multiple small programs for processing logic.

Having multiple handlers should only slightly effect performance and processing millions of messages per minutes is not too much. For example in some benchmarks we were able to handle millions of req / res (HTTP1.1) per second easily.